# multithreading spawn new process when worker has finished

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to define a pool of n workers and have each execute tasks held in a rabbitmq queue. When this task finished (fails or succeeds) I want the worker execute another task from the queue.

I can see in docs how to spawn a pool of workers and have them all wait for their siblings to complete. I would something like different though: I would like to have a buffer of n tasks where when one worker finishes it adds another tasks to the buffer (so no more than n tasks are in the bugger). Im having difficulty searching for this in docs.

For context, my non-multithreading code is this:

```
while True:
    message = get_frame_from_queue() # get message from rabbit mq
    do_task(message.body) #body defines urls to download file
    acknowledge_complete(message) # tell rabbitmq the message is acknowledged
```

At this stage my "multithreading" implementation will look like this:

```
@recieves('ask_for_a_job')
def get_a_task():
    # this function is executed when `ask_for_a_job` signal is fired
    message = get_frame_from_queue()
    do_task(message)

def do_tasks(task_info):
    try:
        # do stuff
    finally:
        # once the "worker" has finished start another.
        fire_fignal('ask_for_a_job')

# start the "workers"
for i in range(5):
    fire_fignal('ask_for_a_job')
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a more built in way to achieve this?

Note `get_frame_from_queue` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to have each subprocess/thread consume directly from the queue, and then within each thread, simply process from the queue exactly as you would synchronously.

```
from threading import Thread

def do_task(msg):
   # Do stuff here

def consume():
    while True:
        message = get_frame_from_queue()
        do_task(message.body)
        acknowledge_complete(message)

if __name __ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for i in range(5):
        t = Thread(target=consume)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
```

This way, you'll always have N messages from the queue being processed simultaneously, without any need for signaling to occur between threads.

The only "gotcha" here is the thread-safety of the rabbitmq library you're using. Depending on how it's implemented, you may need a separate connection per thread, or possibly one connection with a channel per thread, etc.

Comment: problem is that `get_frame_from_queue` is not thread safe. im using stompest to get the message from the queue TFIW.

Comment: stompest only allows 1 connection per ip address by the looks of things.

Comment: I did more or less this, except I used a JoinableQueue, and checked if it was full in an infinite loop. when it was not full I added another message to it from rabbitmq. Then in each of the workers I consumed a message from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to leverage the `multiprocessing.Pool` object.  Use an outer loop to get N items from RabbitMQ.  Feed the items to the Pool, waiting until the entire batch is done.  Then loop through the batch, acknowledging each message. Lastly continue the outer loop.

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(word):
    return bool(word=='whiskey')

messages = ['syrup', 'whiskey', 'bitters']

BATCHSIZE = 2
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(BATCHSIZE)

while messages:
    # take first few messages, one per worker
    batch,messages = messages[:BATCHSIZE],messages[BATCHSIZE:]

    print 'BATCH:',
    for res in pool.imap_unordered(worker, batch):
        print res,
    print

    # TODO: acknowledge msgs in 'batch'
```

### output

```
BATCH: False True
BATCH: False
```

Comment: thanks. problem is I don't want to wait for all in batch to complete before getting next batch, rather when 1 tasks completes move on to next task.